# Gradle on Intellij not syncing

Tags: java, macos, gradle, intellij-idea

Hope you guys are having a nice day!

I am currently working on a project which uses an Older version of Gradle, specifically Gradle 3.0. Hence, I installed the older version and in Intellij set it as the source in Gradle Settings. However, after that was done, I clicked build and it immediately started downloading index files. And as soon as it was done downloading it brought up the following error code:

```
 Unable to find method 'org.gradle.api.invocation.Gradle.getIncludedBuilds()Ljava/util/Collection;'
org.gradle.api.invocation.Gradle.getIncludedBuilds()Ljava/util/Collection;

Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)

Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)
The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this problem.

Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart)
Your project may be using a third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in the project or the version of Gradle requested by the project.

In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.
```

I then went on to Re-Download as it advices, and similarly restart but after building the project again, it gives the same error.

I really don't know where I am going wrong. I have attached an image of what my gradle settings look like and an image of my IDE.

Also out of curiosity, as you can see in the images, in the project directory: There are so many gradle version, what could those mean? It went from 2.14 to 7.5.1 like automatically? I have no idea why.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!! Thank you Again!
[image: My IDE:][image]

Comment: what is your gradle version ? 7.5 or 2.14 ?

Comment: I set it as 3.0, because this project is very old and would only run on that.

Comment: try to set 2.14.

Comment: I can't because I haven't got 2.14 installed. I have only installed 3.0.

Comment: i think your ide will handle this

Comment: How do you mean? I tried and it still doesn't work. Any other ideas?

Comment: This method is supported only since 3.1 Gradle version, see the documentation: https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/invocation/Gradle.html#getIncludedBuilds--

Answer (score 2):

The [getIncludedBuilds](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/invocation/Gradle.html#getIncludedBuilds--) method is supported only since Gradle 3.1 version as documentation shows.

Comment: Intellij use gradle from the 'gradle-wrapper.properties' file by default. If the distributionUlr in the properties file with Gradle 3.0 or older. There seems to be a conflict no org.gradle.api.invocation.Gradle.getIncludedBuilds() found.

Answer (score 1):

try `File->Invalidate Caches` from your IDE or you can Delete `.idea` file from your src folder and run the project again.

Comment: I tried that and it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to invalidate caches and restart option on intellij

Comment: How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Ahh, I just tried that and it still wouldn't work.